# Running backup script at shutdown (using rclone utility)

Tags: systemd, backup, services, shutdown, rclone

**General**: I want to run a back-up script during shutdown (not reboot). I've tried tons of systemd's service configuration, but no one is working.

**Aim**: When PC is shutting down I want to perform a back-up to cloud storage using bash script and [rclone](https://rclone.org/) utility. Syncing may take some time (up to several minutes) and it requires networking and a user being logged in.

**Question**: What the appropriate .service file structure for my bash script ? Now I have something like this and it doesn't work at all. Script doesn't run at shutdown.

```
[Unit]
Description=Syncing with MEGA cloud storage 35
DefaultDependencies=no
Conflicts=reboot.target
After=network-online.target
Before=shutdown.target halt.target poweroff.target

[Service]
User=yevhenii
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/home/yevhenii/Projects/ubuntu-scripts/mega_sync_pc.sh
RemainAfterExit=true
TimeoutSec=0
StandardOutput=file:/home/yevhenii/Projects/ubuntu-scripts/output.txt
StandardError=file:/home/yevhenii/Projects/ubuntu-scripts/error.txt

[Install]
WantedBy=shutdown.target poweroff.target halt.target
```

P.S. I'm using Ubuntu 19.10 & systemd 242

Comment: Why not just add a backup&shutdown icon to your UI?

Comment: because there are several approaches to shutdown. icon / physical button / console (remote). so, systemd way seems to be not so hard coded.